# User Property defined for an ADFv2 activity not being displayed in montior

Tags: azure-data-factory

I created a very simple pipeline just to verify that User Property defined for an activity are being displayed in monitor when the pipeline runs. But it appears that no matter how many user properties I define for the activity, they are not being shown in monitor. I read that the whole purpose of user property is for monitoring, if that itself is not happening I am wondering what is the use of this. So the pipeline just one parameter and one Wait activity. The activity has 2 user properties, one of the properties is getting assigned value of the pipeline parameter while the other user property has a hardcoded string as a value.

Here is the pipeline json:-

```
    {
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "act-Wait",
                "type": "Wait",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "userProperties": [
                    {
                        "name": "UserProperty1",
                        "value": "@pipeline().parameters.sometable"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "UserProperty2",
                        "value": "hardcodedstring"
                    }
                ],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "waitTimeInSeconds": 1
                }
            }
        ],
        "parameters": {
            "sometable": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

When I run the pipeline in debug mode, I instantiate value for the pipeline parameter too, but in the monitoring window (that appears at the lower side of a screen) I don't see any of the user properties defined for the activity. I do see everything else about the activity and its successful status etc.

Comment: I even tried creating a trigger for it and running, still the same. I think this feature is broken. Is anyone else able to see these in monitoring at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User properties is at the activity level, you would need to click on "View Activity Runs" for the pipeline to be able to see it. You can choose to add it as a column for the monitoring view.

[User Properties screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9Qfv.png)